# Exibir valores não nulos

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

bom dia!

Atualmente estou trabalhando com uma tabela no ORACLE em que há 10 campos e alguns desses campos são nulos, de forma aleatória, como o exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de exibir as 10 colunas, porém caso uma coluna seja nula, quero que seja apresentado o o proximo valor não nulo dessa sequencia, como o exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me auxiliar para realizar este procedimento?

Comment: isso não da pra ser feito numa query, precisa de programação. Se for no banco precisa escrever uma procedure pra isso, mas me parece bem complicado fazer isso linha a linha

Comment: Ficaria mais fácil num exemplo real creio , 1) "unpivotear" por "union" as colunas eliminando os nulos  2) "pivotear" novamente por "max" e "case" , mas o problema parece "gasoso" ao menos para mim, fora o modelo que também parece ruim.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, começo com uma frase "Só porque se consegue fazer uma coisa não quer dizer que se deva fazê-la."

A solução apresentada serve apenas para ilustrar que se pode fazer usando apenas validações basicas entre colunas e tabelas temporárias. Mas, com o aumento do número de colunas a solução torna-se difícil de ler, torna-se susceptível de erros e muito provável com baixa performance.

O pressuposto é que, em cada linha, os valores em cada coluna são sempre diferentes.

A solução, que pode ser visível [aqui no Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ffd9c/82/0) , usa apenas 4 colunas (em oposição de 10) mas o raciocinio é extrapolável (mais uma vez - não quer dizer que se deva fazer). Deixo aqui apenas a explicação sumária, - bastante confusa - do raciocínio.

No primeiro passo substitui-se o valor de cada coluna pela sequenciação de `NVL`'s. Isto é, a primeira coluna fica o resultado de `NVL(COLUMN1, NVL(COLUMN2, NVL(COLUMN3, NVL(COLUMN4, NULL))))`, para a segunda `NVL(COLUMN2, NVL(COLUMN3, NVL(COLUMN4, NULL)))`, etc.

Após este passo, os valores da tabela original deixam de ser importantes e só se usam os valores retornados no passo anterior. Para cada coluna:

1. Verifica-se se o seu valor é igual a qualquer um dos das colunas anteriores. Se isso acontecer, passa-se ao passo 2, caso contrário fica com o valor da própria coluna;
2. Verifica se há igualdade com as colunas à direita (comecando na imediatamente à direita, até à última sequêncialmente). A coluna fica com o valor da coluna mais à esquerda até à qual se encontrou correspondência.

Como disse é possível fazê-lo mas não é boa ideia.